# Different mechanisms in isolation is/are not effective?

Tags: verbs, plural-forms, singular

Should I use "is" or "are" in the following sentence?

> Different mechanisms in isolation is/are not effective.

Answer (score 3):

Ask youself: What is the *subject* of your sentence (*"Who does something?"*), then match the verb.

Here, it's "mechanisms", hence use plural: "are".

> Different mechanisms in isolation are not effective.